# ImageView getLayoutParams() returns null

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm creating a widget programicaly with this simple method

```
private ImageView getModuleIconView(Module module) {
    ImageView view = new ImageView(context);
    view.setImageResource(module.getIconResId());        
    view.getLayoutParams().height = 50; //NullPointerException
    return view;
}
```

I get the NullPointer Exception because getLayoutParams returns null. Why is that?

Comment: Because your imageview is on air, you didn't put it on screen. So it has not have any layout params or any size.

Comment: Didn't know that. Yous hould post it as an answer I guess

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Because your imageview is on air, you didn't put it on screen. So it has not have any layout params or any size.

If you want to set image's height to 50 you may consider to set layoutParams of this view... You can set layoutParams' height as 50. So it'll do what you seek.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50));
 img.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

these lines will set your image's height to 50, but don't forget i'm assuming that your parent view as linear layout, if it's not, then you should use its layoutparams.

Comment: I'm a little confused. The constructor for `LayoutParams` accepts another `LayoutParams` object that you also just create on the spot? Can you create only one object in that case?

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin Answer

The reason for this is (likely) that you have just created it and have not yet rendered it on screen. Fortunately, you can set it yourself

```
val width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT // or LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
val height = (context.)resources.getDimension(R.dimen.my_size)

view.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
```

Make sure that `LinearLayout` gets changed to whatever layout you are adding to.